# jquery prop returns NaN but attr returns the correct value

Tags: jquery

Here is my HTML script

```
<td id="balance" amount="9"></td>
```

This jQuery statement returns `NaN`:

```
$("#balance").prop("amount")
```

This jQuery statement returns `"9"`:

```
$("#balance").attr("amount")
```

So what's wrong here? Why the `prop` function does not work here?

Comment: `amount` is not valid property for td element. you should also use `data-*` attribute for adding custom attributes

Comment: You can't add properties, however you can add attributes. However I would recommend `data-` prefixed custom attribute

Comment: [Attributes vs. Properties @ docs. read it.](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Agreed

Comment: @Jai this is quite rude. And the doc actually does not explain what is prop and what is attr. Neither does it mention the `data-*` attribute.

Comment: @Pingu glad you get there but there is no response from the OP, so i guess that is fine for this post and question was not about `data-*` attributes.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar thanks for your answer. So I guess I should use `data-amount` for best practice instead. And then I should still use `attr` to get the attribute of `data-amount` instead of using `prop`?

Comment: No. Use `.data` to get data attributes value. `.data("amount")`

Comment: great thanks. So should I delete this question or just leave it here?

Comment: @PaskinsLoe: you can leave it. i just posted organised answer below based on things said in my comments :)

Comment: would be better explain ! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `amount` is not valid property for td element. You should also consider using data-* attribute for adding custom attributes:

```
<td id="balance" data-amount="9"></td>
```

and then get them using `.data()`:

```
.data("amount")
```